# DateTime Math Works with 2 lines of code but not one

Tags: javascript, datetime

I've come across an interesting Javascript phenomenon that I can't explain.  Let's say I wanted to convert the current time into values ranging from 0.0 to 23.5, in 0.5 increments - ie. 0, 0.5, 1 1.5 ... 22, 22.5, 23, 23.5

This code does that:

```js
const dateTimeNow = new Date();
let currentTime = dateTimeNow.getHours();
currentTime += (dateTimeNow.getMinutes() === 30) ? 0.5 : 0;
console.log(currentTime);
```

But this single line version fails to produce the correct value:

```js
const dateTimeNow = new Date();
let currentTime = dateTimeNow.getHours() + (dateTimeNow.getMinutes() === 30) ? 0.5 : 0;
console.log(currentTime);
```

Hoping someone can explain why!

Comment: What is `dateTimeNow`?

Comment: `=== 30` should probably be `>= 30`, otherwise you're only adding .5 when *getMinutes* returns exactly 30.

Comment: @Barmar : Sorry, fixed it!
@RobG: I actually preset the possible values as indicated in the intro so `=== 30` works fine.

Comment: The code as posted doesn't "work" for me. At 14:44 it returns 14, not 14.5. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your ternary operator, you thing that order of operations should go like this:

`dateTimeNow.getHours() + (dateTimeNow.getMinutes() === 30) ? 0.5 : 0;`

`dateTimeNow.getHours() + 0.5`

`20.5`

In reality, it does this:

`dateTimeNow.getHours() + (dateTimeNow.getMinutes() === 30) ? 0.5 : 0;`

`20 + true ? 0.5 : 0;`

`21 ? 0.5 : 0;`

`0.5;`

To fix this you just need to add another set of parentheses:

`let currentTime = dateTimeNow.getHours() + ((dateTimeNow.getMinutes() === 30) ? 0.5 : 0);`

Comment: This set of parenthesis is redundant: `(dateTimeNow.getMinutes() === 30)`, and `===` should be `>=`. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The reason is operators' precedence. Your expression:

`a + b ? c : d`

Evaluates to:

`(a + b) ? c : d`

And NOT to:

`a + (b ? c : d)`